# i want to capture square video in iOS with custom control

Tags: ios, iphone, video, avcapturesession

i am able to show square preview of recording using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer class, But it saving video in rectangular in library. Instead of rectangle i want square video. I have used composition class to crop video and  it is working but taking too much time. I check vine app which has square video output.

Please give me suggestion.

Comment: Please go more into detail about what it is you want. I do not understand. Do you want to be able to take square video, and play rect video back? or what?

Comment: i want vine app  like video recording. And yes record and save square video. and again play saved video in square preview.

Answer (score 1):

its late answer but it is used for another.. see the my ans

https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision

record video in square